# How to know a entity is going to insert or update

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Because of some limitation, client asked that I can't use incremental "id" primary key, only compound primary key is allowed. And I can't use JPA annotation to have entity callback. Thus how can I know an entity is going to be inserted or updated ?
thanks a lot.

Comment: Is it necessary to know that it's going to insert or update?  A merge should perform either operation depending on if it's attached or not.

Comment: +1 with @kaleb. What is your use case? Why would you need to know if it's a create or delete. And why don't you actually know what you are doing?

Comment: As a platform design, say there is a DefaultManager interface, it has a saveOrUpdate() method which takes a POJO as parameter. Thus DefaultManager is a super class for each model or logic subclass. All subclass will use saveOrUpdate(Entity entity) to do insert or update, even I have a saveOrUpdate(List<Entity> entities) method for bulk update. Within the both saveOrUpdate methods, DefaultManager will mark create time or update time for each entity. That why I need to know each entity's status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a version column

```
@Version
public Integer getVersion() {
    return this.version;
}
```

Whether it is null so it is an insert else it is an update.

regards,

Comment: Thanks a lot. I haven't used Hibernate for years. Since 2.1.7, it has changed a lot, I almost forgot all the basic things.

Comment: or I will use Hibernate EntityManager instead of Spring's HibernateTemplate, thus I can use @PrePersist and @PreUpdate to know the state.

Comment: Feel free to ask for anything else you want. I have many ORM related answers. regards.